# (iterable object in the new array name) Creating multiple numpy arrays with different names using a for loop to break a larger numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, loops, data-analysis

I have a big array "lines" of size (98182, 2). The first column is just a counter which starts from 1 multiple times within the array. So I wrote a small loop to find indices of every time it starts over again.

```
changes             = []
for j in range(len(lines)):
    print(j)
    if lines[j,0]   == 1 :
        changes.append(j)
```

This tells me every index where first column starts from 1 again. The lengths of the smaller arrays are different. The first 5 are like this:

```
[0,
 3643,
 6868,
 8434,
 14347, ...
```

I can write multiple lines like this to slice the large numpy array into smaller ones every time first column is 1 again like this:

```
line1 = lines[changes[0]:changes[1]]
```

since there are 17 smaller arrays within the big one, I do not want to write this line 17 times. Is there a way where I can make these 17 arrays "with different names" using a loop?
I assume that it should be something like this:

```
for i in range(len(lines)-1):
line_[i] = lines[changes[i]:changes[i+1]]
```

but i as the counter cannot be in the name of the array. I do not know how I should proceed with this.

Comment: That's a job for a list of arrays, not a bunch of numbered variables.

Comment: @user2357112 Should I convert the big one into a list? and how would the loop look like then?

Answer (score 0):

Use numpy split which does exactly what you want and produces a List of sub-arrays:

```
result = np.split(lines, changes)
```